# How to create a Stuff and XML PATH(SQL) in Linq or Lambda

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

How to create the equivalent code in Linq or lambda?

I'm using Entity Framework Core on Asp.net Core 2.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
         STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Roles.Name
                FROM AspNetUsers Users
                INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles UserRoles ON UserRoles.UserId = Users.Id
                INNER JOIN AspNetRoles Roles ON Roles.Id = UserRoles.RoleId
                WHERE AspNetUsers.Id = UserRoles.UserId
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')) AS 'Roles', 
    AspNetUsers.*                    
FROM 
    AspNetUsers AspNetUsers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have a query looking like this one.  If you profile the query, you'll notice that the STUFF ... FOR XML PATH part is computed in memory by .NET instead of SQL.

```
var test = (
    from u in ctx.Users
    join ur in ctx.UserRoles on u.Id equals ur.UserId
    join r in ctx.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
    group r by u into g
    select new { User = g.Key, Roles = string.Join(",", g.Select(y => y.Name)) }
           );
```

Side note
It is much easier to work with the query keeping the user as an object, instead of expanding all of its properties